# ng-dirty like functionality in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a form with 100 fields(some are nested like v-model="a.b.c" or v-model="e.h.s.z" ).

Want to implement ng-dirty(from angular) like functionality in vue.js

Don't want to field by field level watch/check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a deep watcher:

```js
watch:
{
  a:
  {
    handler(newValue, oldValue)
    {
      // find out what was actually changed
    },
    deep: true
  },
  e:
  {
    handler(newValue, oldValue)
    {
      // find out what was actually changed
    },
    deep: true
  },
}
```